# Additive Identity of a Vector Space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Looking at the various axioms for vector spaces, I'm getting hung up on this one:

> Additive Identity
>   The set $V$ contains an additive identity element, denoted by $0$, such that for any vector $v$ in V,     $0 + v = v$   and   $v + 0 = v$.

It seems simple enough but in an example given -

$V = \Bigg\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1+x\\2-x\\3+2x
\end{bmatrix}     
\Bigg| x \in \mathbb{R}\Bigg\}$

And the additive identity is -
$0=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$

I'm confused by this as certainly, $v + 0 \neq v$.

I'd appreciate any help in understanding this, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you wrote your example correctly? If so, how do you define your vector space V?

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing *adding the vector 0* with *evaluating with each parameter equal to zero*.  Indeed, if you plug in $0$ for $x$ and $0$ for $t$ in your above example you get $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, however this has nothing to do with adding.

Comment: With your current edit, the way that you have defined $V$, it is not a vector space (for several reasons) given the usual definition of addition.  Are you perhaps somehow using some exotic addition that doesn't follow usual rules for this example?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have edited my question to improve clarity; appreciate the help. {1, 2, 3} is given by them to be the additive identity which they call vector 0 (what a great name...). I understand this vector is found by making x equal to 0, but I'm confused how this fits the definition of the additive identity. Adding the vector 0, which is {1, 2, 3}, and v should equal v?  Perhaps I'm not properly understanding the definition? [Here is the problem in whole](http://i.imgur.com/LH355Ns.png). Sorry for causing so much trouble...

Comment: @Jester: The point is that a vector space is not just a set; a vector space is a set *along with the addition and multiplication* operations (the zero and negation are part of the structure too, but those can be solved for from the addition). For the most part, one cannot say anything at all about a vector space if one only knows the set of vectors. In some cases (e.g. arrays of numbers), there are *conventions* where if no operation is specified, a conventional default is assumed; in this particular problem, the conventional reading gives the *wrong* operation. That's probably confusing you.

Comment: @Hurkyl Couldn't have said it better myself. Why I failed to acknowledge that the defined method of addition was applicable to this part of the problem is beyond me... Lessoned learned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the vector space you are working in is $\mathbb{R}^3$, the set of ordered $3$-tuples of real numbers.  An element in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is often written in the form $\overrightarrow{v}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$.

With $\overrightarrow{v}=\begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix}$ and $\overrightarrow{u}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix}$, we define addition in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the following way:

$\overrightarrow{v}+\overrightarrow{u} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1+u_1\\v_2+u_2\\v_3+u_3\end{bmatrix}$

I.e. we separately add each component.

Given this definition of addition, the only possible zero vector would be $\overrightarrow{0}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

---

In your example, you have $V$ defined as $V=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$

Given a more exotic addition, I'll use the symbol $\oplus$, this could still be made into a group and possibly a vector space where addition is defined in the following way:

$\overrightarrow{v}\oplus \overrightarrow{u} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{bmatrix} \oplus \begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1+u_1-1\\v_2+u_2-2\\v_3+u_3-3\end{bmatrix}$

In this case, as your problem suggests, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ acts as an additive identity, I will denote as $id_\oplus$.  To see this, note that $\overrightarrow{x} \oplus id_\oplus = \begin{bmatrix}1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}\oplus\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+x+1-1\\2-x+2-2\\3+2x+3-3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}=\overrightarrow{x}$

As for closure under addition, suppose $\overrightarrow{x} = \begin{bmatrix} 1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}$ and $\overrightarrow{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 1+y\\2-y\\3+2y\end{bmatrix}$.  Then we have $\overrightarrow{x}\oplus \overrightarrow{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 1+x+1+y-1\\ 2-x+2-y-2\\3+2x+3+2y-3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+(x+y)\\2-(x+y)\\3+2(x+y)\end{bmatrix}$, so $\overrightarrow{x}\oplus\overrightarrow{y}\in V$.

For additive inverse, we want to show that any $\overrightarrow{x}\in V$ has some "$\ominus \overrightarrow{x}$" such that $\overrightarrow{x}\oplus (\ominus \overrightarrow{x}) = id_\oplus$ (where here $id_\oplus$ is the additive identity for $\oplus$ as described above).

Let $\overrightarrow{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}$ and $\ominus\overrightarrow{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1+(-x)\\2-(-x)\\3+2(-x)\end{bmatrix}$.  Then indeed, $\overrightarrow{x}\oplus (\ominus \overrightarrow{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}1+x+1-x-1\\2-x+2+x-2\\3+2x+3-2x-3\end{bmatrix}=id_\oplus$, so additive inverses exist.

Since it is closed under addition, has an additive identity, and has additive inverses for each element, this forms a group.

Given a suitable definition for scalar multiplication (where it essentially ignores the 1,2,3 at the beginning), then we can even make this a vector space.

However, with addition as normally defined, our zero vector should still be the traditional one where each entry is zero.  As a result, since there does not exist any value of $x$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}1+x\\2-x\\3+2x\end{bmatrix}=\overrightarrow{0}$, it will not be a vector space.

We see also that given usual addition $V$ will not be a vector space since it is not closed under addition (how it is usually defined) or scalar multiplication (how it is usually defined).

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful write-up! I find it to affirm much of what I originally thought and call into question more of what the book has written. I think it'd be best to talk to my professor and come to a solid understanding. Again, thanks!

Comment: @JesterJeffrey I only just now saw you posted a link to the full question.  My comments about how you *could* make it into a vector space by defining addition and multiplication happened to coincide with how the book defined it (even going so far as using the symbol $\oplus$ for the exotic addition).  My notation varied slightly, where I referred to each entry of the vector as opposed to the value of $t$, but the definitions are equivalent.  What remains then is to show that it is closed under scalar multiplication and some associativity and distributivity axioms.

Comment: You're absolutely right. @Gaussian0617 just updated his response and I'm slowly starting to piece things together... This is what I get for trying to do math when super tired. :P I think I see now where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem defines addition as follows:
$$ v_1 \oplus v_2 =
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + t_1 \\ 2 - t_1 \\ 3 + 2t_1 \\
\end{array}\right) 
\oplus
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + t_2 \\ 2 - t_2 \\ 3 + 2t_2 \\
\end{array}\right) 
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + (t_1 + t_2) \\ 2 - (t_1 + t_2) \\ 3 + (2t_1 + 2t_2) \\
\end{array}\right) 
$$

So to find your additive identity, you need to find a vector whose elements are defined such that 
$$ v_1 \oplus \text{0} =
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + t_1 \\ 2 - t_1 \\ 3 + 2t_1 \\
\end{array}\right) 
\oplus
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + t_2 \\ 2 - t_2 \\ 3 + 2t_2 \\
\end{array}\right) 
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + (t_1 + t_2) \\ 2 - (t_1 + t_2) \\ 3 + (2t_1 + 2t_2) \\
\end{array}\right) 
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 + t_1 \\ 2 - t_1 \\ 3 + 2t_1 \\
\end{array}\right) 
$$
based on how $\oplus$ have been defined.

For the first element of the additive identity, you need $1 + (t_1 + t_2) = 1 + t_1$.  This will only occur of $t_2 = 0$; in other words, it will only occur if the first element of $v_2$ is $1 + 0$.  Thus, the first element of the 0 is 1.  You can solve for the others in a similar fashion.

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully add clarity. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Jester Jeffrey; your solution is correct according to the way the problem has been written up in the book.  The additive inverse is (1,2,3).  I'm editing my post to address your question after the clarification.

Comment: Okay, wow. Thank you! Slowly piecing things together and seeing where I went wrong. Essentially, the defined method of addition *does* matter in this case (not sure why didn't think it would) and, subsequently, every t2 would need to equal 0 leaving only (1, 2, 3). Can't say thanks enough!

Comment: @JesterJeffrey looks like you've got the hang of it.  Glad to help.